# scss Reuse variables from map in style class

Tags: html, css, angular, ionic-framework, sass

I have a px padding map

```
$sizes: (
  10_px: 10px,
  20_px: 20px,
  30_px: 30px
);
```

how do I refer this in my class

```
.h1 {
  padding: map($sizes, 10_px);
  display: block;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

doesn't seem to work.

Comment: If you want to get a value from map you have to use map-get(): `padding: map-get($sizes, 10_px);` in your case.

Answer (score 2):

i recommend you to use mixins

```
@mixin padding($value) {
  padding: $value
}

.h1 {
  $include padding(14px);
  display: block;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: I also want to create and reuse constants for common sizes; say header_size:24px, and pass $include font-size(header_size); how do I do that?

Comment: you can create multiple mixins, but for a single line of css, you can put inline, font-size: 24px.

Comment: mixins, by default is use to not write multilines everitime and reuse very simple. something like this, with mutiple variables @mixin alignments($margin, $padding, $text-align, $vertical-align, $horizontal-align) etc.